# ¿Cómo ordenar un modelo Django usando la subclase Meta con conversión explícita de tipo de dato?

Tags: django, django-models

¿Cómo puedo hacer un CAST (conversión de un tipo de dato a otro) en el atributo `ordering` de la subclase `Meta` de un modelo en Django?. Aquí está el código fuente:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import IntegerField


class Attendee(models.Model):
    """Modelo de una persona asistente a un evento.

    Arguments:
        models {class} -- django.db.models.Models
    """
    V_NATIONALITY = 'V'
    F_NATIONALITY = 'E'
    NATIONALITY_CHOICES = [
        (V_NATIONALITY, 'Venezolana(o)'),
        (F_NATIONALITY, 'Extranjera(o)'),
    ]
    nationality = models.CharField('nacionalidad', max_length=1, choices=NATIONALITY_CHOICES, default=V_NATIONALITY)
    idc_number = models.CharField('número de CI', max_length=11, unique=True, help_text='Ej. 8.888.888')
    names = models.CharField('nombres', max_length=200, help_text='Ana María')
    surnames = models.CharField('apellidos', max_length=200, help_text='Pérez Pérez')
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [Cast('idc_number', output_field=IntegerField)]
        verbose_name = 'Asistente'
        verbose_name_plural = ' Asistentes'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1} - {2} {3}'.format(self.nationality, intcomma(self.idc_number), self.names, self.surnames)
```

En el admin de Django, muestro la data como una lista (`list_display`) y necesito que se pueda ordenar por el campo `idc_number` de menor a mayor (y viceversa), sin embargo, al ser de tipo `varchar`, el orden es por longitud de la cadena y no por el valor numérico en sí.

Como pueden observar, intenté realizar una conversión de tipos con la función `Cast()` en el atributo `ordering` de la subclase `Meta` pero arroja un error:

```
TypeError: cast_db_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'connection'
```

Hace falta un argumento posicional, el de la conexión pero no sé cómo especificarlo, además no creo que esta sea la forma correcta o idónea de hacerlo. Hace poco que empecé con Python y Django, desconozco muchas cosas, pero ya llevo todo un día, leyendo y buscando y no logro dar con la manera de hacerlo.

¿Tendré que cambiar el campo `idc_number` en el modelo a tipo `int`, muy a pesar que no tenga que hacer cálculos aritméticos?

Help

Comment: Te complicas demasiado, simplemente cambia el campo `idc_number` a [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) si solo contendrá números, o también puedes utilizar el campo [`PositiveIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) para aceptar solo números positivos. Por otra parte para que crees que existe dichos campos? **Existen para guardar números o enteros** ni mas ni menos, el hecho de que no vayas a hacer cálculos aritméticos sobre el valor del campo no significa que no debas de utilizarlo.

Comment: De hecho es raro que guardes **solo** enteros como `str` o `VARCHAR`, etc, en la db. Para eso existen dichos campos, si solo vas a guardar números, entonces guárdalos como enteros en la db, al no hacerlo vas a confundir a alguien que lee tu código, pues por algo utilizaste el campo `CharField` no? van a pensar que el valor del campo no solo serán números si no letras también.

Comment: Mmm... pasa que al final de cuentas esos números se van a tratar más como texto que como números en sí, por ejemplo, concatenarle otros caracteres u otros campos de la misma tabla. Pero parece que sí, como que es complicarse la vida de gratis, jeje.

Comment: Si los vas tratar como texto, **es decir guardar cadenas(`string`) en la db,** entonces si debes utilizar el campo `CharField`. Pero depende de lo que quieras hacer, pero lo ideal es que utilices el campo `CharField` para **guardar cadenas de texto en la db**.

Comment: A decir verdad, quería guardarlos ya formateados con el punto como separador de miles, forzando al usuario a escribir el número con los puntos necesarios o mediante algún JS añadir los puntos automáticamente en el formulario html, para evitarme el `cast` en las consultas SQL. Pero en Django con `intcomma` de `django.contrib.humanize` como que se resuelve la cosa.

Comment: Bueno, Suerte! :)

Answer (score 1):

después de tanto buscar y tantos intentos...

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import F, PositiveIntegerField


class Attendee(models.Model):
    """Modelo de una persona asistente a un evento.

    Arguments:
        models {class} -- django.db.models.Models
    """
    V_NATIONALITY = 'V'
    F_NATIONALITY = 'E'
    NATIONALITY_CHOICES = [
        (V_NATIONALITY, 'Venezolana(o)'),
        (F_NATIONALITY, 'Extranjera(o)'),
    ]
    nationality = models.CharField('nacionalidad', max_length=1, choices=NATIONALITY_CHOICES, default=V_NATIONALITY)
    idc_number = models.CharField('número de CI', max_length=11, unique=True, help_text='Ej. 8.888.888')
    names = models.CharField('nombres', max_length=200, help_text='Ana María')
    surnames = models.CharField('apellidos', max_length=200, help_text='Pérez Pérez')
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [Cast(F('idc_number'), output_field=PositiveIntegerField())]
        verbose_name = 'Asistente'
        verbose_name_plural = ' Asistentes'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1} - {2} {3}'.format(self.nationality, intcomma(self.idc_number), self.names, self.surnames)
```

Sin embargo, en la vista del administrador de Django al reordenar la tabla que muestra los datos por el campo `idc_number`, reordena por el tipo de dato original, es decir, reordena como un `string` .

Bue... como bien comentó [Julio Cesar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/106915/julio-cesar) mejor lo guardo como `PositiveIntegerField`, al fin y al cabo son números... y positivos solamente...